# Handle high number of traditional synchronous/blocking HTTP client requests with few threads Java?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, http, asynchronous

I am working with Java. Another software developer has provided me his code performing synchronous HTTP calls and is responsible of maintaining it - he is using `com.google.api.client.http`. Updating his code to use an asynchronous HTTP client with a callback is not an available option, and I can't contact the developer to make changes to it. But I still want the efficient asynchronous behaviour of attaching a callback to an HTTP request.

(I am working in Spring Boot and my system is built using RabbitMQ AMQP if it has any effect.)

The simple HTTP GET (it is actually an API call) is performed as follows:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

This server I'm communicating with via HTTP takes some time to reply back... say 3-4 seconds. So my thread of execution is blocked for this duration, waiting for a reply. This scales very poorly, my single thread isn't doing is just waiting back for a reply to arrive - this is very heavy.

Sure, I can add the number of threads performing this call if I want to send more HTTP requests concurrently, i.e. I can scale in that way, but this doesn't sound efficient or correct. If possible, I would really like to get a better ratio than 1 thread waiting for 1 HTTP request in this situation.

In other words, I want to send thousands of HTTP requests with 2-3 available threads and handle the response once it arrives; I don't want to incur any significant delay between the execution of each request.

I was wondering: how can I achieve a more scalable solution? How can I handle thousands of this HTTP call per thread? What should I be looking at or do I just have no options and I am asking for the impossible?

EDIT: I guess this is another way to phrase my problem. Assume I have 1000 requests to be sent right now, each will last 3-4 seconds, but only 4-5 available threads of execution on which to send them. I would like to send them all at the same time, but that's not possible; if I manage to send them ALL within the span of 0.5s or less and handle their requests via some callback or something like that, I would consider that a great solution. But I can't switch to an asynchronous HTTP client library.

Comment: You will never increase concurrency beyond X threads.  Just create a ExecutorService with your target thread number and add your Requests in the form of Runnable objects.  They will all eventually execute.

Comment: Eventual execution is not enough. If I create an executor service with 2 threads, can I execute 1000 Requests without any significant delay between each request?

Comment: Unless your current HTTP client library supports callbacks, you will have to change to another that does. As posed, your question embodies several contradictions in terms.

Comment: Any kind of pointers regarding clarification on 'contradiction of terms' would be considered helpful and constructive towards both solving the problem at hand and at providing the members and future members of this community with helpful, fruitful discussions and material.

Comment: For example: 1. High concurrency with a blocking library but only using a small number of threads. 2. Trying to use a callback mechanism in a library that doesn't have one without changing the library.

Comment: There is no contradiction. This is the circumstance that has been dealt to me via dependency on another external library. This SO thread is about exploring what can be done in that situation and the answer seems to be a mere 'nothing'.

Comment: the answers are in the comments, you just don't like them.

Comment: To pontificate: You're insisting these need to be _blocking_ calls; they're not. You are simply waiting for a response and doing a greedy wait by continually polling for an update. By using callbacks, you roughly put your request out, submit it to a queue to wait for responses, and act on them when they do respond. While you're waiting, those requests no longer block (because they don't have to), allowing you to send more. Keep in mind a client rate limit is usually a good thing to not get yourself blackholed from an api service.

Comment: I don't want them to block, but they block. An external developer provided me with a library using blocking calls in this way and changing his code is not at all an option. What should I look at, more concretely, to extend upon this code I was provided to eliminate this greedy wait? This is what I am here for. A client rate limit does not concern my application.

Comment: The fact that you've been *given* contradictory requirements doesn't stop them being contradictions. Contradictions don't have solutions. You are asking for the impossible. Try to accept that.

Comment: Maybe specify some of the reasons you can't change this library, but if you really can't modify it at all the only alternative is pretty much throwing more hardware at it or changing the underlying executable for the entire language.

Comment: I can't change this library as my company doesn't have the time to allocate to (a) rewrite and debug/verify the new branch now, let alone to (b) deal with the maintenance/synchronization necessary that comes afterwards as the original code we are branching off of keeps getting updated. Anyway, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Are you sure this the `com.google.api.client.http` that you are using? The code you're showing `HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());` looks furiously like it's using the new Java 11 HTTP Client [1]. In which case it you could use `HttpClient.sendAsync` instead of  `HttpClient.send`. 

[1] https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using an asynchronous HTTP client is **not an available option** - I can't change my HTTP client library.

In that case, I think you are stuck with non-scalable synchronous behavior on the client side.

The only work-around I can think of is to run your requests as tasks in an `ExecutorService` with a bounded thread pool.  That will limit the number of threads that are used ... but will also limit the number of simultaneous HTTP requests in play.  This is replacing one scaling problem with another one: you are effectively rate-limiting your HTTP requests.

But the flip-side is that launching too many simultaneous HTTP requests is liable to overwhelm the target service(s) and / or the client or server-side network links.  From that perspective, client-side rate limiting could be a *good* thing.

---

> Assume I have 1000 requests to be sent right now, each will last 3-4 seconds, but only 4-5 available threads of execution on which to send them. I would like to send them all at the same time, but that's not possible; if I manage to send them ALL within the span of 0.5s or less and handle their requests via some callback or something like that, I would consider that a great solution. But I can't switch to an asynchronous HTTP client.

The only way you are going to be able to run > N requests *at the same time* with N threads is to use an asynchronous client.  Period.

And *"... callback or something like that ..."*.  That's a feature you will only get with an asynchronous client.   (Or more precisely, you can only get real asynchronous behavior via callbacks if there is a real asynchronous client library under the hood.)

---

> So the solution is akin to sending the HTTP requests in a staggering manner i.e. some delay between one request and another, where each delay is limited by the number of available threads? If the delay between each request is not significant, I can find that acceptable, but I am assuming it would be a rather large delay between the time each thread is executed as each thread has to wait for each other to finish (3-4s)? In that case, it's not what I want.

With my proposed work-around, the delay between any two requests is difficult to quantify.  However, if you are trying to submit a large number of requests at the same time and wait for all of the responses, then the delay between individual requests is not relevant.  For that scenario, the relevant measure is the time taken to complete *all* of the requests.  Assuming that nothing else is submitting to the executor, the time taken to complete the requests will be approximately:

```
 nos_requests * average_request_time / nos_worker_threads
```

The other thing to note is that if you did manage to submit a huge number of requests simultaneously, the server delay of 3-4s per request is *liable* to increase.  The server will only have the capacity to process a certain number of requests per second.  If that capacity is exceeded, requests will either be delayed or dropped.

> But if there are no other options.

I suppose, you could consider changing your server API so that you can submit multiple "requests" in a single HTTP request.

I think that the real problem here is there is a mismatch between what the server API was designed to support, and what you are trying to do with it.

And there is definitely a problem with this:

> Another software developer has provided me his code performing synchronous HTTP calls and is responsible of maintaining it - he is using com.google.api.client.http. Updating his code to use an asynchronous HTTP client with a callback is not an available option, and I can't contact the developer to make changes to it.

Perhaps you need to "bite the bullet" and stop using his code.  Work out what it is doing and replace it with your own implementation.

There is no magic pixie dust that will give scalable performance from a synchronous HTTP client.  Period.

Comment: So the solution is akin to sending the HTTP requests in a staggering manner i.e. some delay between one request and another, where each delay is limited by the number of available threads? If the delay between each request is not significant, I can find that acceptable, but I am assuming it would be a rather large delay between the time each thread is executed as each thread has to wait for each other to finish (3-4s)? In that case, it's not what I want. But if there are no other options...

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and thorough answer. Regarding "biting the bullet", this is certainly not an option, as the code is far too sophisticated to be rewritten and to deal with the maintenance that comes after that as he keeps producing his updates and I produce mine to achieve the same behaviour.

Comment: Well then, you need to just live with it.  Sorry, but there are no solutions.  (And this is not Java's fault.  You would have the same problems / roadblock in any implementation language ... given the constraints that you have stated.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that was what I wanted to clarify here. Just for clarification, would you be able to elaborate on why wrapping my synchronous HTTP client call in some CompletableFuture to handle its Future callback not be a solution?

Comment: Nope.  Not a solution.  (Think it through.  Your synchronous HTTP call uses a thread ... from the time the call starts until it complete.  Most of the time, the thread will be blocked in syscalls waiting for the server response.  This is how a synchronous HTTP library works.)